# select snps based on non-significant HWE using tableHWE in SNPassoc package in R

Tags: r, genetics

I am running a GWAS analysis using the SNPassoc package. I want to conduct this analysis in two steps: 1. Test all snps to determine if they are in hardy-wineburg equilibrium(HWE); 2. Run a test of association on the snps that are found to be in HWE(correcting for false discovery using a Bonfirroni correction).

To conduct these analyses, I am attempting to use the SNPassoc package in R. Using this package, one first transforms the data using the function setupSNP:

`myData<-setupSNP(data=SNPs,colSNPs=1:10,sep="")`
In this example, lets say column 1 is some categorical dependent variable and 2-10 are snps with three levels (AA,AB,BB)

Once the data is in this format, you can test for HWE across all snps using the following function:

`res<-tableHWE(myData)`

Producing the following double where a flag <- points to p values that are <=.05

```
        HWE (p value) flag
rs001        0.6211                      
rs002        0.8866                        
rs003        0.8210            
rs004        0.8474            
rs005        0.8364            
rs006        0.4969            
rs007        0.7229            
rs008        0.0345        <-
```

I can also conduct an automated set of comparisons doing the following:

```
ans<-WGassociation(myData$DV~1,data=myData)
```

producing the following result:

```
          comments codominant dominant recessive overdominant log-additive
rs001          -    0.63396  0.60907   0.56673      0.34511      0.98948
rs002        -    0.43964  0.30132   0.65763      0.20148      0.53629
rs003          -    0.76300  0.79052   0.46217      0.90503      0.60872
rs004        -    0.54956  0.35198   0.39842      0.64349      0.27900
rs005         -    0.37222  0.32537   0.53702      0.15989      0.71894
rs006         -    0.32753  0.18286   0.84399      0.13830      0.34471
rs007            -    0.82284  0.75360   0.68389      0.56956      0.95867
rs008         -    0.77077  0.48628   0.73038      0.53702      0.47055
```

What I want to do is select only those snps that are in HWE (i.e. p >.05) and then conduct the association tests on only those. Does anyone have an idea about how to do this? I can't find it in the documentation(see bellow)

see: (http://davinci.crg.es/estivill_lab/tools/SNPassoc/SupplementaryMaterial.pdf) for documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to subset your data.frame down to the rows that contain SNPs with a HWE P > 0.05, and then run the association test on the remaining values. With base R:

```
# example object containing all snp data
all_snps <- data.frame(SNP_ID=paste("POS_", 1:1000, sep=""), stat1=sample(100, size=1000, replace=TRUE))

# example object containing hwe test
res <- data.frame(SNP_ID=paste("POS_", 1:1000, sep=""), HWE_P=runif(1000))

# subset the rows where P is > 0.05, extact vector of SNP IDs
SNPS_in_HWE <- subset(res, HWE_P > 0.05)$SNP_ID


# you can subset your "all snp data" object to the rows where the SNP ID is in the list of SNPs with P > 0.05
snps_in_HWE_subset <- all_snps[all_snps$SNP_ID %in% SNPS_in_HWE,]

# run the WGassociation function with this subset 
ans<-WGassociation(snps_in_HWE_subset$DV~1,data=snps_in_HWE_subset)
```

Comment: I think this is a good general solution. But is think it needs to be tweeked to work in this instance. WGassociation() takes data in the class setupSNP which is double. If you look at head(res) above in the example above, there's no label for the snp column. When I run your code, its a data.frame with a label. How would you approach this problem given the data format?

Comment: If your snp names are row names instead of values within a column, add a column where you assign values equal to row names: `res$SNP_ID <- rownames(res)`